# Check if YouTube video is live or uploaded

Tags: javascript, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have a YouTube Live Event. I am able to play the video using the YouTube IFrame Player API. I want to know if there is any way that I can find if the video is a Live event video or a regular uploaded video. I need this information for designing my controls.

Comment: Use [player.getDuration()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Retrieving_video_information). If it is live stream, it will return 0 [Demo](http://jsbin.com/zuzogofoje/edit?html,console,output)

Comment: Thank you. But, If I try getDuration() before the video even starts playing. Here, isn't there a chance that getDuration() returns 0 for an uploaded video?  "Note that getDuration() will return 0 until the video's metadata is loaded, which normally happens just after the video starts playing"

Comment: Hey Moni, any updates?  Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 6):

The only way you can do this (currently) is with [youtube backend api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos).
Get data about the video based on its id and in the response you have a property `snippet.liveBroadcastContent` which is either **live, none, or upcoming**.

Answer (score 1):

The IFrame API provides a [Playback quality](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en#Playback_quality) function which returns a string representation of the current video quality.

From my tests, this function will return an undocumented string `auto` for live events.

Related discussion can be found in [this issue](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/47) on YouTube's iOS Player Helper Library's GitHub page.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it.

Comment: The 'Playback quality' isn't working for me. I tried with some youtube videos and getPlaybackQuality() returns 'unknown' for some of the uploaded and live events and it didn't return 'auto' for any of the samples i tried. Sorry for delayed update, was busy with another project.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this works any more. I'm just getting 'large'.